# Meaning of 梛 (나무 이름 나)

Tags: hanja

[梛 (나) has the meaning of "나무 이름" in the dictionary,](http://m.hanja.naver.com/hanja?q=%E6%A2%9B) but does this mean the name of some particular tree or just the "나" in 나무? If the former, which tree name? If the latter, it seems strange to me because as far as I know 나무 is not Sino-Korean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get any useful information related to that, so I looked up 百度(Baidu, Chinese site) instead of local networks and this is what it said:

- 百度百科(Baidu Encyclopedia): 梛，拼音为nuó，指一种树。古书上说的一种树。这种树现在有多个名称...

[ Translation: 梛, pronounced as 'nuo', means a kind of tree. You can find it to say a kind of tree in old books. This specific kind of tree has many names these days... ]

http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%A2%9B/7808671

So it looks like 梛 is describing a specific kind of tree, not the 나 in 나무.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a Chinese speaker who pointed me to this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nageia_nagi

Comment: @ryanbrainard In Japanese, that kanji 梛 is used for that same species: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8A%E3%82%AE. Though the hanzi is attested in the Kangxi Dictionary, its description doesn't really match though.